# Watson Discovery Box connection expired credentials

Tags: watson-discovery

I am not able to connect my box folder to Watson Discovery Service. i have provided all the credentials needed but I am the following Error every time I submit it.

Failed to retrieve the instance resource. The account named acc_name has invalid or expired credentials.

i queried a lot on the internet but was unable to get a solution. If anyone familiar could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Were you using an Enterprise scope App or Application scope App?
While entering the private key in WDS configuration, please make sure that you copy the entire value generated by Box including `=\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\n`

I would recommend reauthorizing the App, to make sure that the changes take into effect.

Please make sure that you have the below Application scopes set in your App configuration:

- Read and write all folders stored in Box
- Manage Users
- Manage Enterprise Properties
- Generate User Access Tokens

Note: If you change any settings on your Box App, please make sure to reauthorize the app.

Comment: I am using an application scope

Comment: I also noticed that in the box settings, there's no instance of my app being created in the my application tab. However in the dev console I have created the same

Answer (score 0):

Then it looks like your App hasn't been created successfully. I would recommend you to try creating a new Box App

1) Navigate to Box Developers Console Example: https://app.box.com/developers/console and click Create New App.

2) From the Create a New App screen, select Enterprise Integration and click Next.
On the Authentication Method screen, select OAuth 2.0 with JWT (Server Authentication) and click Next.

3) Name your app and click the Create App button.

Once your Box app has been created, click View Your App and follow the steps to configure the application scopes as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the missing steps. You need to go to Admin Console -> Apps then Authorize New App then go back to App Configure page to generate public/private keys.